# Pass Parameter From Controller to Custom AuthorizationHandler

Tags: authentication, .net-core, authorization

I'm working on a controller that allows people to share access to updating a website. I'm trying to work on an AuthorizationHandler that verifies that the current user has access to update the website they're trying to update.

My current Request and AuthorizationHandler

```
public class WebsiteRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public WebsiteRequirement(int websiteId)
    {
        WebsiteId = websiteId;
    }

    public int WebsiteId { get; private set; }

}
```

```
internal class WebsiteAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<WebsiteRequirement>, IAuthorizationHandler
{
    private readonly IWebsiteLogic _websiteLogic;

    public WebsiteAuthorizationHandler(IWebsiteLogic websiteLogic)
    {
        _websiteLogic = websiteLogic;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, WebsiteRequirement requirement)
    {
        int userId = int.Parse(context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "UserId").Value);

        // Use the _websiteLogic to check if user has access, based on user id and website Id
        if(_websiteLogic.CheckUserAccess(userId, requirement.WebsiteId)){
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I know you can use the AuthorizationHandler to create Policies that are fairly dynamic, like below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
      options.AddPolicy("WebAuth", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new WebsiteRequirement(1)));
  });

    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, WebsiteAuthorizationHandler>();
}
```

But would it be possible to pass that `1` in from the controller? I don't want to have to create a new policy for each new website (I also want to reuse this similar structure for a variety of other similar use cases. My last-resort is to have a SecurityService that I call on every call from the controller, but that really doesn't seem elegant, but I also haven't seen anything that allows what I'm trying to do.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Policy = "WebAuth", WebsiteId=[FromBody]website.id)]  // Trying to do something like this
public ActionResult<WebsiteDto> SaveWebsite([FromBody] WebsiteDto website)
{
    if(_websiteLogic.CheckUserAccess(CurrentUserId, website.Id)) // My Backup Solution
    {
        return _websiteLogic.AddWebsite(website);
    }
    return new UnauthorizedResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to pass in values from the HTTP request then you can access these values by the `Resource` property on the `AuthorizationHandlerContext` passed into the handler ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#accessing-mvc-request-context-in-handlers)).

If you're just trying to pass in some configuration type setting then make sure your `AuthorizationHandler` has lifetime Transient and pass those values in on the constructor.

Comment: So the issue I forsee there is that I'm not ALWAYS going to have the same http request structure. EX: If I do a GET on `api/websites/2` then the websiteId is 2. If I do a POST, then I want to grab the websiteId out of the `website` object. Is it good practice to have that sort of conditional in an AuthorizationHandler?

Comment: @ChrisHobbs I wouldn't like to comment on best practices; you certainly _could_ do that though... 